# Precise graphic placement in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm making slides using beamer but am having trouble placing images where I want them.  My code is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}{Plume/jet description}

  \hspace{-1em}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (plumeModel) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{images/image1}
      };
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (collapsing) at (6.75,0) {
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{images/image2}
      };
      \draw[-latex,thick] (plumeModel.east) -- (collapsing.west) node (arrow) [midway,above] {};
      \draw[-,thin] (plumeModel.east) -- (collapsing.west)  node [midway,below] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Parameters}
        Mean velocity: $\bar{u}$ \\
        Plume radius: $b$ \\
        Buoyancy: $g' = g\dfrac{\rho - \rho_a}{\rho_0}$
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

      \begin{block}{Conserved fluxes}
        Volume flux: $q = b^2 \bar{u}$ \\
        Momentum flux: $m = b^2 \bar{u}^2$ \\
        Buoyancy flux: $f = g' q$
      \end{block}

    \end{column}

  \end{columns}

  \vspace*{\fill}

\end{frame}
```

This is the result.  They're too far to the right of the slide.  How do I get them centred?  I've tried playing with the `\hspace` command but this either does nothing (for small spacing values), or does too much (when the spacing value is larger).  I can't get fine control.

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 2):

I think your images are not far to the right but your columns far to the left.

When `columns` are used, `beamer` considers a longer line, left and right margins are shorter and first column is moved to the left compared with regular paragraphs.

It's possible to avoid this behavior applying option `onlytextwidth` to `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Plume/jet description}

%  \hspace{-1em}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,draw,outer sep=0pt] (plumeModel) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
      };
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,draw,outer sep=0pt] (collapsing) at (6.75,0) {
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
      };
      \draw[-latex,thick] (plumeModel.east) -- (collapsing.west) node (arrow) [midway,above] {};
      \draw[-,thin] (plumeModel.east) -- (collapsing.west)  node [midway,below] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Parameters}
        Mean velocity: $\bar{u}$ \\
        Plume radius: $b$ \\
        Buoyancy: $g' = g\dfrac{\rho - \rho_a}{\rho_0}$
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Conserved fluxes}
        Volume flux: $q = b^2 \bar{u}$ \\
        Momentum flux: $m = b^2 \bar{u}^2$ \\
        Buoyancy flux: $f = g' q$
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \vspace*{\fill}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]